# Unable to authorize to a OAuth 2 legged provider

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, oauth, oauth-2.0, 2-legged

I am trying to authenticate to a 2 legged OAuth(1.0) system from ruby irb as follows using oauth ruby gem,

**Step 1:**

```
require 'oauth'

irb(main):038:0> consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new("key", "secret", :site => "site", :scheme => :query_string)
I got a response for this as,


 => #<OAuth::Consumer:0xba14be2c @key="{got valid key here}", @secret="{got valid secret here}", @options={:signature_method=>"HMAC-SHA1", :request_token_path=>"/oauth/request_token", :authorize_path=>"/oauth/authorize", :access_token_path=>"/oauth/access_token", :proxy=>nil, :scheme=>:query_string, :http_method=>:post, :oauth_version=>"1.0", :site=> "https://example.com/">
```

**Step 2:**

```
irb(main):039:0> access_token = OAuth::AccessToken.new consumer

=> #<OAuth::AccessToken:0xba144b7c @token="", @secret="", @consumer=#<OAuth::Consumer:0xba147430 @key="{got valid key here}", @secret="{got valid secret here}", @options={:signature_method=>"HMAC-SHA1", :request_token_path=>"/oauth/request_token", :authorize_path=>"/oauth/authorize", :access_token_path=>"/oauth/access_token", :proxy=>nil, :scheme=>:query_string, :http_method=>:post, :oauth_version=>"1.0", :site=>"https://example.com/"}>, @params={}>
```

**Please see Token is empty above.** I should have got the token here??

**Step 3:** Then i tried all the paths which i got from above,

```
irb(main):041:0> access_token.get("/oauth/authorize")   
irb(main):041:0> access_token.get("/oauth/request_token")
irb(main):041:0> access_token.get("/oauth/access_token")
```

But for all the request am getting response as,

```
=> #<Net::HTTPNotFound 404 Not Found readbody=true>
```

I dono where i am making mistake, am i doing the request correctly, if not how should i authenticate to the 2legged oauth system in ruby. Or should i ask the service provider to check on their side.

Token field is empty in step 2, that is the problem??.

Can anyone please guide me in this?? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this code will help:

```
require 'oauth'
consumer_key = <your consumer key>
consumer_secret = <your consumer secret>
end_point = "https://www.example.com"
consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(consumer_key, consumer_secret, {
                                                 :site   => end_point,
                                                 :scheme => :header
                                             })


parameters = "user_id=1"

resp = consumer.request(:post, '/get_user/', nil, {}, parameters, { 'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' })
```